# Computer detects Windows 7 operations system twice

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot, bcd

After using the following commands in windows repair iso:

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr 
bootrec.exe/FixBoot 
bootrec.exe/RebuildBCD 
bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
c: 
cd boot attrib bcd -s -h -r 
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

The computer starts up asking if I want to run "Windows 7" or "Windows 7", and once it starts up it says that windows is not genuine. I tried using the repair iso and before it opens it gives me the same two options. It says select an operating system to repair

Operating system,Partition Size,Location:
Windows 7 Perfessional 152625 MB            (C:)Local Disk
Windows 7 Perfessional 152625 MB            (C:)Local Disk

Its the same thing twice.....

Does anyone know how i can reverse these commands??
[image: (http://www.3image.com/images/2013/01/12/IMG00944-2010112-2041.jpg pic)]

Comment: Seems like you were using not-genuine Windows with [loader](https://www.google.am/search?q=windows+7+laoder)-style cracks (probably it was built-in). That cracks create another boot record and make OS load from that second "Windows 7". Try running the second (or both of them), is one of them working? If no, running the same cracker usually helps, but it's illegal and can cause security issues. Buying license key is better.

Answer (score 1):

Once Windows is loaded, run `msconfig`. Go to the "Boot" tab. Check to see that the two options listed are really identical. If they are, select one of them and delete it. Restart your computer and it should automatically boot from the only option left. The genuine/activation part you should probably post as a separate question unless it is directly linked to this two entries problem.